# WPF .NET App Cannot Connect to SQL Server on Different Network

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, server, database-connection

My WPF application cannot connect to an external SQL Server. The host machine has port 1433 open, has a static IP address, and port forwarding from the IP address to host server has been enabled.

Most puzzling, I am able to connect from SQL Server Management Studio on the client machine using the same connection name, and same server authentication details, but I cannot connect with my .NET application. I am using Entity Framework, which is working until the app is built and queries the server.

Therefore, I have ruled out server hosting issues, and connection string issues, as I'm able to connect while working on Visual Studio, but cannot connect while app is running.

The error (inner exception) is

> TCP provider, error 0 - Access is Denied

Answer (score 0):

if you are able to connect through SSMS remotely to sql server there should not be problem for connecting through application using ado.net, you need to recheck your ef configuration and connection string

I assume you are using entity framework 6.
Based on the approach like code first based or designer model based you need to validate your configuration

Please refer to below link
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/fundamentals/configuring/connection-strings

If you are using ef core refer to below link and validate your configuration for connection string

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/connection-strings